# extracting data to state isn't like documentaion - in mapStateToProps in react native and redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am new to react native and redux. when I connect my component to the store, and used mapStateToProps function in order to map the state to the component props, I noticed that the component state is located at state.component_reducer, for example if I store a variable called isFetching in my component then I can reach it in state.isFetching (as I read in react redux documentation) but in my case I can reach it at state.component_reducer.isFetching.
I think I am doing something wrong but I couldn't figure out what is it.

**actions.js**

```
import OrdersAPI from '../../services/api/Orders'

export const REQUEST_ORDERS = 'REQUEST_ORDERS'
export const RECEIVE_ORDERS = 'RECEIVE_ORDERS'

export const requestOrders = username => ({
    type: REQUEST_ORDERS,
})

export const receiveOrders = (json) => ({
    type: RECEIVE_ORDERS,
    orders: json
})

const fetchOrders = username => dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestOrders(username))
    return OrdersAPI.getUserOrders(username)
      .then(json => dispatch(receiveOrders(json)))
}

// temp imp
const shouldFetchOrders = (state) => {
    const orders = state.orders
    if (!orders) {
      return true
    }

    return false;
}

export const fetchOrdersIfNeeded = username => (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (shouldFetchOrders(getState() == true)) {
      return dispatch(fetchOrders(username))
    }
}
```

**component reducer - reducer.js**

```
import { REQUEST_ORDERS, RECEIVE_ORDERS } from './actions'

const INITIAL_STATE = {    
    orders: [],
}

function orders(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case REQUEST_ORDERS:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            ...state,
        })
        case RECEIVE_ORDERS:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {   
            ...state,
            orders: action.orders,
        })
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default orders;
```

**my component - OrdersList.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import OrderCard from './OrderCard';
import { fetchOrdersIfNeeded } from './actions'

class OrdersList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { dispatch } = this.props
        dispatch(fetchOrdersIfNeeded("X"))
    }

  render() {
       const { orders } = this.props;
       const isEmpty = orders.length === 0
    return (
        isEmpty ? 
            <View>
                <Text>Wishlist Empty!</Text>
            </View> 
        :
        this.props.orders.map((order) => (
            <OrderCard key={order.OrderId.S} order={order} />
        ))
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

    const orders = state.ordersReducer.orders;
    return {
      orders
    }
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(OrdersList);
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
import wishlistReducer from '../components/WishlistGridList/reducer'
import ordersReducer from '../components/YourOrders/reducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    wishlistReducer,
    ordersReducer
})

const middleware = [ thunk ]
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  middleware.push(createLogger())
}

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(...middleware)
);

export default store;
```

Comment: You have not provided all the relevant code: not the `../components/*/reducer` imports in your `store.js`. Likely one or both of them do something like `combineReducers({component_reducer});` which will explain why the shape of your state is not quite what you expected.

Comment: you right, the reducer I provided is ordersReducer, the one I didn't provided is wishlistReducer, and its exactly the same implementation as ordersReducer.
and I am doing it right, right ? I just return the reducer function, didn't used combineReducer in component reducer